# Can we use SAGA name for a third party Framework?

Tags: spring-boot, design-patterns, frameworks, saga

I have been creating a free and open source framework for microservices using SAGA design pattern. I have named it as `ActionSAGA`. But i have a doubt whether a third party company like us can use that name or not as a suffix. Because we are using that concept as well.

I want to know there's is a possibility to have a leagal problem regarding the name in the future?

Please consult me by professionals. Thank you!

I wish to have a leagal advice.